# How to know if MySql's conditional INSERT worked?

Tags: mysql, node.js, sql-insert, insert-into

With a conditional Insert, I want to know if a row was inserted or if overlap was found.

I have a query that inserts a request into the database if it doesn't overlap with any existing entry. The query works, but how do I know if there's been an collision? The query just executes successfully. Here is my query:

```
INSERT INTO requests(id, start_time, end_time)
   SELECT NULL, 1463631640671,1463636731000,
   FROM Dual
   WHERE NOT EXISTS (
     SELECT * FROM requests
         WHERE
             start_time < 1463638531000 AND
             end_time > 1463636731000
    )
```

For your information. I'm doing this inside Node.js with the mysql package.

and the code looks like this, and it returns 'SUCCESS' every time.

```
var queryString = "INSERT INTO requests(id, start_time, end_time..."

connection.query(queryString, function(error, results, fields) {
    if (!error) {
        console.log('SUCCESS!');
    }
    else {
        console.log('Insert into requests unsuccessful.');
        console.log('ERROR: ' + error);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can inspect `results.insertId` and see if you have something in it.